# Get passwords from Joomla user tables and use them in a codeigniter application

Tags: codeigniter, joomla, authentication, md5, salt

On my server I have a website running Joomla. Inside public_html I have created a new directory and, inside this directory, there's my Codeigniter application. Altough I'm new to Codeigniter and Joomla, I'm trying to build a login form using Codeigniter. 
I don't want to create a new table to store user information, since I have already such information in Joomla. I want to retrieve user information (usernames and passwords) from a Joomla table called #_users, but the problem is that the password is stored in a different way in Joomla. It uses md5 and a salt string. 
Here's my model in Codeigniter:

```
<?php
Class User extends CI_Model{

function login($username, $password){
  $dbjoomla = $this->load->database('my_joomla_db');
  $dbjoomla-> select('id, username, password');
  $dbjoomla-> from('users');
  $dbjoomla-> where('username', $username);
  $dbjoomla-> where('password', md5($password));
  $dbjoomla-> limit(1);

  $query = $dbjoomla-> get();

    if($query -> num_rows() == 1){
     return $query->result();
    }
    else{
     return false;
    }
  }
 }
```

I'm able to connect to the user table of Joomla (because $dbjoomla is not empty and is set), but the code is not working yet because of the password format stored in Joomla. I can retrieve it by using only md5($password). 
How can I get the Joomla passwords and have them verified on my Codeigniter application? Is that possible?

Comment: Judging by you saying `md5 and a salt`, I hope you're aware this applies for Joomla 2.5. Bcrypt is used for Joomla 3.2 onwards, just so that you know :)

Comment: I would just follow the code from the Joomla authentication and user plugins and JUser exactly.  You don't ever get the users's password all you can do is check whether the password the user has entered matches the encrypted password in the table.  Please don't fool around with authentication unless you have studied it carefully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how Joomla encrypt their passwords, but they probably have the salt in the database.

First you select ->where('username', $username);

Then since you should be getting 1 row, You'll be using ->row() method instead of ->result()

```
$dbjoomla = $this->load->database('my_joomla_db');
$q = $dbjoomla
           ->select('id, username, password, salt')
           ->from('users')
           ->where('username', $username)
           ->get();
$row = $q->row();
```

Now You have the row that contains the encrypted password & the salt, lets make sure the password entered by the user is correct (You'll have to review Joomla to make sure how the encrypt the password -- This is just an example)

```
$JoomlaEncryptedPassword = md5($PasswordGivenByUser.$row->salt);
if ( $JoomlaEncryptedPassword === $row->password ) {
   return $row;
}else{
   return FALSE;
}
```

As shown above we're replicating the encryption done by Joomla & comparing it to the stored password in the database, if the information are OK we return the row, otherwise we return FALSE

Now the concept is clear to you, all you have to do is dig through Joomla files to see how they encrypt the password so you can implement it.